# MS Access cursor location in continuous form

Tags: ms-access, continuous-forms

I have a contunuous form where editing is disabled. If you want to edit an entry you have to select the line in a table and click the button "Edit".

The problem is when the form loads it's allways the first line of the table that is selected by default and if you click the "Edit" button a from will open with values from the first line of the main form.

What I want is the cursor to be set to nowhere when the form opens and if you click the "edit" button a message box would appear saying that no record is selected. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Put a header on the form, and put a textbox in the header that has the form's name or something.  In the Load event of the form, set the focus to the textbox in the header.  Something like:

```
Me!txtMyTextBox.SetFocus
```

That should get the focus off your continuous form.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work. When I click the "Edit" button after opening the form it still opens the first record.

Comment: I used macro OpenForm for the Edit button

Comment: You need to write VBA code that opens the form and determines which record is selected, instead of relying on some stock macro.  There's really not a lot of info you've given me that helps me determine the issue, and I'm surprised this question hasn't been closed by mods due to lack of research effort.  Next time you ask a question, please include details about all code you've tried and include them in your post.  Not trying to be a jerk, but this is how the site works.

Comment: I thought about writing the code for the button itself but the arrow symbol in the Record Selector would still show that the first record is selected. I don't want it poiniting to any record. I did a lot of research on this topic and I didn't find anything useful. I didn't include any code because there is nothing to include, it's just a standard continuous form.